# emulate a click on a span jquery

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

Hi is there any way to emulate a click on a span when an user click's an image in another location of the page? Can you use for example

```
<div id="g1">
<span>hey</span>
<span>second hey</span>
</div>

<div id="a2">
<img id="img" src="....."/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#img', function(){
$('#g1 > span:first-child').trigger('click');
```

Will this work or is there any other form to emulate the click on the first span when the user clicks the image?

What if the span you need is in an iframe and the image clicked is outside the iframe?

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Comment: Nop it did not but I then saw that I had an error on my code anyway thank you very much for your answers I hope this helps other people too

Comment: Is there any real difference between using click() or trigger('click')? any performance difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it will work, i created fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/De9Z6/

You can use `trigger('click')` or `click()` either.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a standalone function like:  ClickHandler().

Then you can assign it to any event of any element.
And your code will be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("#image").click(function() {

       $('#g1').find('span:first').click();
 });
```